# l5-Swagger Data Type undefined

Tags: laravel-5, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I am using `laravel 5.2.*` and i am using `darkaonline/l5-swagger : ~3.0` for the API's Documentation. I am sending parameters in header body and when I see the Swagger UI its shows me like below.

> Data Type undefined

See below image for more details.

[image: Swagger UI]

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *   path="/api/v1/compaign_attr",
 *   summary="List compaign attributes",
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="campaign_id",
 *     in="body",
 *     description="ID to fetch the targeted compaigns",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Property(property="request", type="json", example={ "campaign_id": 818, "code":"PLATFORM", "type":"Message"}  )
 *   ),
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="x-api-key",
 *     in="header",
 *     description="api key validation",
 *     required=true,
 *     type="string",
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=200, description="successful operation", @SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example={ "aa": { "bb", "cc" } }  )),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=401, description="not authorized"),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=500, description="internal server error")
 * )
 *
 */
```

Comment: Please post your Swagger JSON/YAML file, or if it's generated from code - the code of `POST /api/v1/compaign_attr` (with annotations, etc.)

Comment: @Helen! I added the annotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger PHP - how to define a nested property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37342495/113116)

Answer (score 1):

L5-Swagger does not have data type `json`. You need to set your parameter schema as object through swagger definition or inline schema.

```
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     in="body",
 *     name="body",
 *     required=true,
 *     description="ID to fetch the targeted campaigns.",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *         @SWG\Property(property="campaign_id", type="integer", example=818),
 *         @SWG\Property(property="code", type="string", example="PLATFORM"),
 *         @SWG\Property(property="type", type="string", example="Message")
 *     ),
 *   )
```

[This his how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJyWk.png)